# How to convert if expression into sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have any expression which now i need to run on my sql database record please help me with sql here is the code

```
if (( (gpa == edu.gpa || gpa <= 0) && (edu.gpa.Equals(gpa) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(gpa))
```

i tried similar to convert into sql query like

```
SELECT *
FROM education
WHERE (gpa >= somevalue OR gpa =0 )
AND (degree = 'somevalue' OR degree is NULL)
```

this query does not return correct result if user enter empty values in filter .

Comment: Where are the `somevalue` and `'somevalue'` coming from? Is that a parameterized query or are they hard-coded values? Or are those variables that represent user input?

Comment: they are coming from input form from UI layer .

Comment: if user does not want to apply filter on gpa or degree then query should return entire record in table .

Comment: so if user do not input then what do you expect?

Comment: What do you expect to see when GPA is 0 and no degree is specified?

Comment: The user's empty value is probably "" (the empty string) and not NULL.

Comment: what else is your tag? php asp ..

Comment: @AlainCollins yes if user leave blank the degree field then it should not apply any filter on degree and show entire records

Comment: @raheelshan i m working in java

Comment: Your query will not return records where GPA is NULL or degree is an empty string.

Comment: if made above filter in c# with simple arraylist to retrieve values. but now i want to get results from sql query

Comment: its working fine with gpa if i place gpa as 0 if user does not want to add filter on gpa but having problem with degree

Comment: if user doesnt pass value in degree then pass empty string and use query as mentioned by @PM77-1

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM education
WHERE (gpa IS NULL OR gpa >= somevalue OR gpa =0 )
AND (degree is NULL OR degree = 'somevalue' OR TRIM(degree) = '')
```

Try [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6841/1) and let me know.

Comment: @Junaid Akhtar - I created SQL Fiddle (DEMO) and posted the link into my answer.  You can put your data there and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT *
 FROM education
 WHERE (degree = 'somevalue' OR degree is NULL)
 HAVING gpa >= somevalue OR gpa =0
```

Comment: Why put the gpa comparisons in a `HAVING` clause?  What's wrong with an `AND` condition?